Should I use, Google Auth Token to Verify my Client, If so then How?
I am implementing authentication on my website using Google Auth. After successfully logging in, Google returns a JWT (JSON Web Token). I need to decode this JWT to extract user information and verify its authenticity using a private key.
I have the following requirements:
Securely decode the JWT token.
Verify the token's signature using the provided private key.
Extract the user information from the token payload using Python. But Is this Secure?
`import jwt
def decode_jwt(token):
try:
decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False},algorithms=["RS256"])
return decoded_token
except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
return "Token has expired"
except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
return "Invalid token"
jwt_token = ""
decoded_token = decode_jwt(jwt_token)
print(decoded_token)``your text`

This Verify the Google ID token on your server side page may help answering your question.
